# Unable to properly Import OBJ file in Blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, objects, import

How does it happen and a solution for this?

I'm learning how to animate in blender and I'm using 3d files i found only for free because i can't draw to create a mesh.

So i found this at https://grabcad.com/library/jeepney-1

When i imported it in blender it became like this

[image]

But i open it in meshlab it look like this

[image]

In mesh lab i tried to save as obj again to check if it solve the problem but the problem is still there. Blender doesn't properly Import the file.

What is the solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]For me, it imported into Blender HUGE.  Took me a minute playing with the View clipping to see it.

You can try Clamping the bounds (in the import window) to set a maximum X dimension, for example.

But once I brought it in, it looks fine.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm very sorry i am new to blender. can you please provide screenshot? Thank you

Comment: the so-called "N" menu is shown in my pic above.  In it is the View tab.  You'll see Clip Start and End.  That's where your 3D view will begin and end.  Often times, adjusting these settings will reveal "hidden" or missing objects.  In reality they've just been clipped from your view.

Comment: That bus imported for me something like 30000 meters large.  WAY too big for my view settings.  The import Clamping option allows you to set a largest dimension.  In my shot above, I Clamped the X dimension at 100m, and you can see it came in at 85.4m.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out